# What does the interactionActivityTrackingTag(_:) method do?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, nsuseractivity

I recently came across the [interactionActivityTrackingTag(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/interactionactivitytrackingtag(_:)) method. It was released on iOS 16, and I’m looking for information about it.

The following doc's example tracks the scrolling activity of a List:

```
List {
    Section("Today") {
        ForEach(messageStore.today) { message in
            Text(message.title)
        }
    }
}
.interactionActivityTrackingTag("MessagesList")
```

How to use the created "MessageList" tag? What it is used for? Are there some related methods to work with?

Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess it's providing a SwiftUI access to an ability to preserve the app state via activities: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsuseractivity/creating_a_user_activity_object

Comment: Thanks for the great tip! So we create NSUserActivity objects at key moments. And with its help, we could continue later or on another device from that activity.

interactionActivityTrackingTag(_:) method uses the tag to track user interactions hosted by this view as activities. So we consider user interaction as activity and use tag to track it.

When you create an NSUserActivity object, you specify a string that identifies the type of the activity. Will this identifier be the equivalent of a tag?